# res.redirect() doesn't work except with CTRL-R: a caching issue?

Tags: express, redirect, caching, google-cloud-datastore

I think I have a kind of "cache problem" with Express (I use Google Datastore as a DB).

When the `delete` route below is triggered:

- My item is correctly deleted from DB
- `res.redirect()` works fine
- But my `dashboard` still show the deleted item -> **I need to CRTL-R to see it disapear...**

My `delete` route:

```
router.post('/delete', async (req, res) => {
  await deleteOneHouse(req.params.houseID)
  res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate')
  res.redirect('/dashboard')
})
```

If needed, the `deleteOnHouse` func.

```
async function deleteOneHouse(ID) {
  try {
    const houseKey = datastore.key(['data', ID])
    datastore.delete(houseKey).then(() => {
      console.info(`House ${ID} deleted`)
      return
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

Do you have any clue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`console.log()` is surely your friend to debug.

The `res.redirect()` was triggered BEFORE the end of `delete` op.
Add an `await` and it works fine.

`Post` route to delete:

```
router.post('/delete', async (req, res) => {
  // Delete this house
  await deleteOneHouse(req.params.houseID)
  // Redirect to Dashboard
  res.redirect('/dashboard')
})
```

`Delete` func.

```
async function deleteOneHouse(ID) {
  try {
    const houseKey = datastore.key(['data', ID])
    const deleted = await datastore.delete(houseKey)
    console.info(`House ${ID} deleted`)
    return
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}
```